# Need to get current working organisation of people via names

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to search current working organisation of people by their names and maintain an alumni database. Which LinkedIn API product should I apply for or are all people searching APIs closed from LinkedIn's side?

I searched for People API but some answers mentioned that its no longer supported or is closed.